# A few (very) easy puzzles

Tags: logical-deduction

1. There are 7 sisters in a house. First one is reading a book, second is cooking, third is playing chess, fourth is solving sudoku, fifth is doing the laundry, sixth is watering the flowers. Question: what is seventh sister doing?
2. When do we say "ten" while looking at number 2?
3. A person can get it multiple times. First 2 times are free, but starting from 3rd he has to pay for it. What is it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the last sister doing?](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2703/what-is-the-last-sister-doing)

Comment: Indeed, the first part is a dupe. I'm voting to leave open because of the second and third parts.

Comment: Please only ask one question per... question.

Comment: 2. When it's written in binary

Answer (score 4):

1

> Posting about her family on stackexchange. In this wondrous modern age, sister #3 could be playing chess with just about anyone on the planet.

3

> A set of teeth. Deciduous teeth first, adult teeth second, false teeth third.

Answer (score 3):

1

> seventh is playing chess with the third sister

2

> 10 minutes past some hour in analog clock or watch

3

> Hair-color: First a person gets the natural hair color(free), then he gets graying of hair(free), after this if he wishes to change the color of his hair then he has to pay for the color and/or the saloon service

Comment: not bad, but 2 and 3 are not what I meant. Also, when I see binary I normally read it as "one-zero-one-one-zero" etc and not "10 billion, 110 million, 11 thousands hundred and one"